# SQL Query with WHERE definitions are from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM CallRecords 
WHERE DNIS = '3216547' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

But in the WHERE statement for DNIS ='' and I am looking to take the 3216547, but have it look at another table that I have a list of different DNIS's, for example:

```
3216547
9874560
7418523
```

So normally the statement would be:

```
SELECT * FROM CallRecords 
WHERE (DNIS = '3216547' OR DNIS = '9874560' DNIS = '7418523') 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This query with three is fine, but I am looking to make this where there could be 400 DNIS entries to select from.  Would I be able to do a subquery in the WHERE clause or is this even possible.

Comment: Yes you can do it with a subquery.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I did `SELECT * FROM CallRecords 
WHERE DNIS = (SELECT * FROM DNISList) 
ORDER BY date DESC` and it says : `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM CallRecords 
WHERE DNIS IN (SELECT DNIS FROM DNIS_TABLE)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

If you need all DNIS from the other table you could do that query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM CallRecords
WHERE DNIS IN (SELECT DNIS FROM OtherTable [...])
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the numbers from a different taale you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM CallRecords 
WHERE DNIS IN (SELECT DISTINCT DNIS FROM DNIS_TABLE) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a join rather than a subquery. If you need to filter the dnis values on the other table, do so using the where clause as you usually would.

```
select c.*
  from callrecords c
  join dnis_tbl d
    on c.dnis = d.dnis
 order by date desc
```

However if the other table contains more than one row for each value of dnis, you will need to use a subquery in the where clause to reduce it to one row (would likely perform better than using distinct if it is properly indexed).